# class dictionary not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm still pretty new to python so please bear with me. I'm practicing classes and objects in python so I started this bank account class. There are two types of bank accounts: an individual or business. The business account inherits some behavior from the individual but I'm not completely finished with that.

The problem here is that whenever I deposit an amount, let's say 50 for example, the dictionary doesn't update the value to the corresponding key (the name of the account holder), I'm expecting the value to be updated whenever someone withdraws or deposits into the account - for example: initial balance = 50 deposit = 50, dict updates name and balance to initial balance + deposit

```
import sys
import self

#print a menu so user can pick
def menu():
    print("Welcome to Wells Fargo!")
    print("Lets get started!")
    print("1. Open Individual Account \n"
          "2. Open Business Account \n"
          "3. Check Individual Account \n"
          "4. Check Business Account \n"
          "5. Exit")
    #if user doesnt type number or 1,2,3 , throw error
    try:
      choice = int(input("Please enter your choice here: "))
    except ValueError:
      print("Oops! Looks like you didnt type something correct, please try again!")
    if choice == 1:
      print("Creating Individual account...")
      #create object representing account info
      #set name method
      individual.set_name(self)
      #set balance method
      individual.set_balance(self)
      #call menu
      menu()
    elif choice == 2:
      print("Creating Business account...")
      #create object representing account
      name = str(input("Enter your name here: "))
      start_balance = int(input("Enter the balance you want to start with: "))
      save = int(input("Enter how much you want to deposit in your savings account: "))
      #add object to list
      bacc = Business(name, start_balance, save)
      #call menu
      menu()

    elif choice == 3:
      print("Loading Individual Accounts..")
      #call check individual accounts method
      individual.check_accounts()
    elif choice == 4:
      print("Loading Business Accounts...")
      #call check business accounts method
      Business.check_accounts()
    elif choice == 5:
      #exit the program
      print("Thank you for using wells fargo, have a nice day!")
      sys.exit(0)

#ask user if ready
def prompt_user():
    try:
      ready = int(input("Are you ready to open/access a account?1=Yes,2=No"))
    except ValueError:
      print("Oops! You did not type something right, please retry!")
    else:
      menu()

#individual bank account class
class individual:
  #initialize defaults (name, balance, &ilst)
  def __init__(self, balance=0, transaction=0,name=''):
    self.balance = balance
    self.transaction = transaction
    self.name = name
    self.idict = {}

  #get the name of the account owner
  def set_name(self):
    self.name = str(input("Enter the name of the account owner here: "))
    #add name to dictionary
    idict[self.name] = 0

  #get balance user wants to start with
  def set_balance(self):
    self.balance = int(input("Enter how much money you want to deposit into your account: "))
    #if amount is less than 25, throw error
    if self.balance < 25:
      print("ERROR! Low Amount, must be greater than or equal to 25")
    #else add it to the dictionary
    else:
      idict[self.name] = self.balance

  global idict


  idict = {
    "John Adams": 5000,
    "Josh Adkins": 4000
  }

  #return object as a string , is this needed??
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)

  #add money & calculate
  def __add__(self,other):
    balance = self.balance + other.balance
    transaction = self.transaction + other.transaction
    return balance + transaction

  #subtract money & calculate
  def __sub__(self, other):
    balance = self.balance + other.balance
    transaction = self.transaction + other.transaction
    return balance - transaction
    #return individual(self.name, self.balance)

  #return user balance
  def __int__(self):
    #search for user name
    for x,y in idict.items():
      if self.name in idict:
        print("fetching account balance...")
        print(int(self.balance))
        break;
      else:
        print("ERROR! Looks like you arent registered in our system!")
        individual.imenu()


  #individual account menu
  def imenu():
    #1. balance, 2. transactions(add, subtract) 3. close acc 4. exit 
    print("1. Get Account Balance \n"
          "2. Deposit $$ \n"
          "3. Withdraw $$ \n"
          "4. Close Account \n"
          "5. Exit")
    choice2 = int(input("Enter your choice here: "))
    if choice2 == 1:
      individual.__int__(self)
    elif choice2 == 2:
      add_money = int(input("Enter the amount here: "))
      sum1 = individual(self.balance, 0)
      sum2 = individual(self.balance, add_money)
      idict[self.name] = sum1.__add__(sum2)
      print("Money added!")
      individual.imenu()
    elif choice2 == 3:
      sub_money = int(input("Enter the amount here: "))
      individual.__sub__(self, sub_money)
    elif choice2 == 4:
      individual.close_account(self)
    elif choice2 == 5:
      print("Goodbye!")
      sys.exit(0)     



  #loop thru indiv acc(s)
  def check_accounts():
    #have user type in their name and check if they have an open account
    enter_name = str(input("Enter your name here: "))
    for key,value in idict.items():
      #check if name is in list
      if enter_name in idict:
        print("Your account was found! Proceeding...")
        individual.imenu()
      else:
        print("Looks like you dont have an individual account, please create one!")

  #close individual account
  def close_account(self):
    print("Type in your name to proceed with account deletion: ")
    try:
      #have user type in their name
      type_name = str(input("Type it here: "))
    except ValueError:
      #if user types anything other than name, throw error
      print("Looks like you typed something incorrect! Please retry!")
    #search business account dict , 
    for x,y in idict.items():
      #if the name is in the, dict remove it
      if type_name in idict:
        del[type_name]
      #if the name is not in the dict, redirect to menu
      else:
        print("Looks like you dont have an account! Please create one!")
        menu()

#call methods
prompt_user()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your problem, what result you expect and what result your have

Comment: updated ! @CorentinLimier

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. Where does that `self` module come from? That's a pretty strange & confusing module name! There are some odd things going on in that class, eg the `global idict`, and some methods are missing their `self` arg.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your given code fails to run (`self` package missing), and appears to require user input to exhibit the error.  It is not at all minimal.

Comment: ok, sorry about that @Prune

Comment: Sorry to bear the bad news but there are many issues here that you should start with before you get into trying to get a balance update to work, I'm going through the whole thing now, hopefully will be able to shed some light on things for you!

Comment: no ones perfect at the end of the day, plus im new! your help is appreciated! @vash_the_stampede

Comment: Of course! I'm actually going through this whole thing, I enjoy it going try to give you a little better framework that you can play with and work with that will help keep things moving as your learning instead of getting too stuck, Ill start a chat when I'm ready if your interested

Comment: yes! that would help a lot! thank you! @vash_the_stampede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bud I only have so much time a day to spend on this but I worked out a little better framwework for you to play with, try using elements in here working with it and modifying it, the skeleton of it should help you get all your goals accomplished with this certain code. I'll be back with more updates when I have time just wanted to give you something to play with! Enjoy!

```
class Account:
    """set stuff"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = []

    def set_name(self):
        print(self.accounts)
        self.name = input("Enter the name of the Account Owner: ")
        self.accounts.append(self.name)
        print(self.accounts)

    def set_balance(self):
        self.balance = int(input("Enter Starting Balance: "))

    def deposit_amount(self):
        self.deposit = int(input("Enter Deposit amount: "))
        self.balance += self.deposit

    def withdrawl(self):
        self.withdraw = int(input("Enter Withdrawl Amount: "))
        self.balance -= self.withdraw

    def close_account(self):
        name = input("Enter the Account Name: ")
        if name in self.accounts:
            self.accounts.remove(name)
        else:
            print("Account not Found.")
            self.imenu()

    def imenu(self):
        print("\n1. Get Account Balance\n"
              "2. Deposit\n"
              "3. Withdraw\n"
              "4. Close Account\n"
              "5. Exit\n")
        choice = -1
        while choice not in range (1, 6):
            try:
                choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
            except ValueError:
                continue
        if choice == 1:
            print(self.balance)
            self.imenu()
        if choice == 2:
            self.deposit_amount()
            print("Money added")
            self.imenu()
        elif choice == 3:
            self.withdrawl()
            self.imenu()
        elif choice == 4:
            individual.close_account()
            return
        elif choice == 5:
            return

class Individual(Account):
    pass

class Business(Account):

    def savings(self):
        self.savings = 0

    def savings_deposit(self):
        self.s_deposit = int(input("Enter Deposit amount to Savings: "))
        self.savings += self.s_deposit


while True:
    print("\nAre you ready to open/access an account? 1 = Yes, 3 = No")
    ans = 5
    while ans not in range(1,2):
        try:
            ans = int(input("Enter either 1 or 2: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue

    print("\nWelcome to the Bank!")
    print("\nSelect and option from the Menu")
    print("1. Open Individual Account\n"
          "2. Open a Business Account\n"
          "3. Check Indiviudal Account\n"
          "4. Check Business ACcount\n"
          "5. Exit")
    select = -1
    while select not in range(1, 6):
        try:
            select = int(input("Please enter your selection: "))
        except ValueError:
            continue

    if select == 1:
        print("\nCreating Individual Account...")
        individual = Individual()
        individual.set_name()
        individual.set_balance()

    elif select == 2:
        print("\nCreating Business Account...")
        business = Business()
        business.set_name()
        business.set_balance()

    elif select == 3:
        print("\nLoading Individual Accounts...")
        name = input("Enter your Name: ")
        if name in individual.accounts:
            print("\nYour account was found! Proceeding...")
            individual.imenu()



    elif select == 4:
        print("\nLoading Business Accounts...")
        name = input("Enter name of Business: ")
        if name in business.accounts:
            print("Your account was found. Proceeding...")
            business.imenu()
        else:
            print("Account not found.")

    elif select == 5:
        print("Thank you for using Bank, Have a Nice Day!")
        break
```

Comment: still does not update the account balance sadly :(

Comment: Take a peek and try reasoning some of the direction of this and make it your own!

Comment: ahhh looks a lot cleaner! I like it, ill definitely see what else I could do with this! The only thing is that a dictionary would be good as it can have a key and a value (account owner and balance) but nevertheless, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Cheers! If i have time I'll play with it some more best of luck! I highly recommend the books Python Crash Course, Automate the Boring Stuff, and Python the Hard Way

Comment: I fixed it and it works very well now thanks to you! I appreciate people like you, thanks a lot! @vash_the_stampede

Comment: @nathanHeath, No worries bud I’m just paying it forward and you now can continue the cycle :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you setup your individual account using `self`. In Python, the term `self` is analogous to `this` in other languages and refers to the instance of the class you're working with. So, rather than use `individual.set_name(self)` you should use `individual.set_name()`.

As for your specific problem, it stems from this method:

```
def set_balance(self):
    self.balance = int(input("Enter how much money you want to deposit into your account: "))
    #if amount is less than 25, throw error
    if self.balance < 25:
        print("ERROR! Low Amount, must be greater than or equal to 25")
    #else add it to the dictionary
    else:
        idict[self.name] = self.balance\
```

You only ever set the balance and don't consider how much is in there. Instead, you should try this:

```
new_balance = int(input("Enter how much money you want to deposit into your account: "))
if (self.name in idict):
    idict[self.name] += new_balance
else:
    idict[self.name] = new_balance
```

This will either add the selected amount to what's there or add to the dictionary.

As an aside, you should avoid asking for input in your class method as this is bad architecture. Instead, give your `set_balance` method another argument called `amount` and use that in place of your input.

I would also advise against overloading `__add__` and `__sub__` unless you have an analogy to the mathematical operations that makes sense. In your case, it doesn't really make sense to add two bank accounts to get a third so it's probably not a good idea.

Then there's your `individual` class. It's very strange how you mix instance and global variables together. Your class has things like `name` and `balance` that I would expect of a bank account class and then there's `idict`, which contains a global mapping of all accounts.

I would suggest submitting this code to a code review board because there are a lot of problems in it and I think you'd benefit from a more exhaustive criticism of the code.